# Why is text inside HTML tags getting translated when requested while Web Scraping?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am learning a little bit about web scraping and currently i am trying to do a small project. So with this code I am storing the HTML code inside `soup` variable.

```
source=requests.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')
```

The problem is: when I inspect the code inside my browser it looks like this:

```
<a ...>The Godfather</a>
```

but when I try to use it in my program only the text inside  tag **(The Godfather**) gets translated to my native language (**Кум**):

```
<a ...>Кум</a>
```

I dont want it to get translated.
My browser is completely in English and I have no idea why is this happening. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify `Accept-Language` HTTP header in your request:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_100&sort=user_rating,desc"

headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")


for h3 in soup.select("h3"):
    print(h3.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
```

Prints:

```
1. The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
2. The Godfather (1972)
3. The Dark Knight (2008)
4. The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)
5. Schindler's List (1993)
6. The Godfather Part II (1974)

...
```

Comment: I added the `headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}` that you posted, to my code and also added headers atribute to the .get method `source=requests.get(URL , headers=headers)` and it SOLVED my problem. Thanks!